# How to retrieve public email address of Facebook Business Page using Graph API?

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently I'm using Facebook's **Graph API** and the **PHP SDK** to retrieve information and recent wall posts from a Business Page.

Included in this data is public information such as name, address and phone number. Whilst public email address can be seen on the page when you visit it on Facebook, it does not appear on the public Graph API (with or without an access token).

Is there a way to retrieve the public email address that I have missed out on?

I suppose I'm aware that technically it's possible to scrape the page, but that's not an elegant or reliable solution.

[Link to example Facebook Page](https://www.facebook.com/cupcakesmuenchen?sk=info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that at this time there is no way to retrieve the publicly available email address using the Graph API without ugly screen scraping.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the [graph-api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) documentation it doesn't look like email is available.

Here's [Wir Machen Cupcakes](https://graph.facebook.com/cupcakesmuenchen?access_token=2227470867|2.AQBJ28IR8pNEopg8.3600.1308762000.0-227302317|fCEUGNvbgg6Ce1ua1Mv7RXRxzrM) information from the graph-api.

Comment: Yes, I know how to retrieve data from the Graph API. I was wondering if there was a way to to get data that appears to be public on the page but isn't included in the public Graph API.

Comment: My mistake scraping the page is best bet but like you said not reliable.